# Concatenate fields inside a trigger

Tags: sql, concatenation, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger to create emails based on first name and last name.
Basically, when populating a table, if an email is NULL, I want to automatically create an email of firstname.lastname@company.com

This is what I have come up with. I know it's the concatenate that is throwing everything off.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail On PersonID
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PersonID
        SET Email=
            (SELECT(RTRIM(FirstName), RTRIM(LastName)) FROM PersonID)
    WHERE Email IS NULL;
END
```

The error message I get is `Incorrect syntax near ','`.

When I insert `SET Email=UPPER(FirstName)` instead of the RTRIMs, it all works, and all NULL emails are altered to the first name so I'm confident in the rest of the code. So the issue, I believe, is with how to properly concatenate the fields of firstname+lastname.

Comment: what database system are you using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail On PersonID
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PersonID
        SET Email= SELECT RTRIM(FirstName)+''+RTRIM(LastName) FROM PersonID
    WHERE Email IS NULL;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly reference the columns of FirstName and LastName in the table itself, as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail On PersonID
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PersonID
        SET Email=CONCAT(RTRIM(FirstName), RTRIM(LastName))
    WHERE Email IS NULL;
END
```